# javascript regex needed, numbers in brackets only, multiple

Tags: javascript, regex, match

**For update / problem solution scroll down** [or click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616123/javascript-regex-needed-numbers-in-brackets-only-multiple/60619442#60619442)

**Orig. question:** I want to write a function in pure javascript which uses the Jquery-like selector with :eq(0) declarations, let's say e.g. to iterate trough a table like

```
$('tr:eq(8) > td:eq(13)').val();
```

For this I am trying to write a regex and I stuck here

```
var str = "I don't want +5+ and not 10 or [12] nor (120) but :eq(5) and :eq(120)";
var matches = str.match(/\:eq\(\d+(\d{1,2})\)?/g);
console.log('matches: '+matches);
```

which returns only `matches: :eq(120)` but not `matches: :eq(5),:eq(120)` as wanted.
What can I do here ?

Comment: What about `/\:eq\((\d{1,3})\)/g` to match between 1 and 3 digits?

Comment: Yes this works too, more sophisticated regex as in Wills answer, but not needed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your regex:

```js
var str = "I don't want +5+ and not 10 or [12] nor (120) but :eq(5) and :eq(120)";
const matches = str.match(/:eq\(\d+\)/g);
console.log('matches: '+matches);
```

Comment: Soooo simple, I must have been blind ... 1+ and accepted answer, thanks

Comment: There're no needs to escape the colon.

Comment: @Toto you're right, one character less. the less the better :-)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE SUCCESS / RESULTS** to share my toughts:

I have a table

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td><span>1</span></td>
        <td><span id="span2">2</span></td>
        <td><span>3</span></td>
        <td><span>4</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><span>5</span></td>
        <td><span>6</span></td>
        <td><span>7</span></td>
        <td><span>8</span></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

and using the previous answers I wrote this small script, which is the beginning of a simple selector engine.

```
const ltrim = (haystack, needle) => {
    var regex = new RegExp('^'+needle);
    return haystack.replace(regex, '');
}

const rtrim = (haystack, needle) => {
    var regex = new RegExp(needle+'$');
    return haystack.replace(regex, '');
}

const $ = (s) => {
    var el = document;

    if (!s.match(/:eq/g)) {
        var cut_index = Math.max(s.lastIndexOf('>'),s.lastIndexOf(' '))+1;
        var last = s.substring(cut_index);
        if (/#/.test(last)) el = el.querySelector(s);
        else el = el.querySelectorAll(s);
    }
    else {
        var m = s.match(/:eq\(\d+\)/g);
        var p = s.split(/:eq\(\d+\)/g);
        for (i in p) {

            if (p[i] == '') i++;
            else {
                if (i == p.length-1) {
                    if (p[i].match(/#/)) el = el.querySelector(p[i]);
                    else el = el.querySelectorAll(p[i]);
                }
                else el = el.querySelectorAll(p[i])[m[i].match(/\d+/g)];
            }
        }
    }
    return el;
}
```

Now I can iterate trough the table using jquery-like selector syntax with

```
alert($('table tr td span#span2').innerHTML); // 2
alert($('table tr:eq(1) td:eq(1) span:eq(0)').innerHTML); // 6
alert($('table tr:eq(1) td:eq(2) span')[0].innerHTML); // 7
```

and I am happy for now. This expression, e.g.

```
$('table tr:eq(1) td span').forEach(elem => {elem.classList.add('yellow')});
```

uses regular JS syntax to highlight a complete row, or just one cell:

```
$('table tr:eq(1) td span:eq(2)').classList.add('yellow');
```

I'm not sure about the support of other jquery-like css selectors, will see in the future. In case of improvements further updates will be here.